# Are there any drawbacks of using "npm run eject" in "create-react-app" setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've got some suggestions that we should try to skip doing "npm run eject" while working with "create-react-app". It also add some extra dependencies in package.json.

How does doing "npm run eject" effects the project? Will there be any negative effect on the size, loading, speed, maintenance or any thing related to the project?

If yes, then what alternate should we use?

Comment: I've read that it means you can't take advantage of updates to 'create-react-app' as easily once you've ejected, BUT if you need to customise your config to the degree that you need to eject, then... then you need to eject, no other way around it. I've had needs before where I couldn't figure out how to configure my application without ejecting, so if that's your case, just do it.

Comment: What are your motives for ejecting? `create-react-app` is a bootstrap for React projects, it simply shields all of the complexity (with tooling) and gets you up and running very quickly. By ejecting, you're given the responsibility of these tools and gives you the ability to customise your project's setup. You could also use [create-react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) if you need some level of customisation but as mentioned, it depends on your motives.

Comment: @Dan: Doing "npm run eject" to add support for less or any other library like dynamically import of antd styles or adding aliases to the folders/files. Also I explored "create-react-app-rewired". It's mentioned that "Stuff can break". Isn't it good to use "npm run eject" which is suggested by "create-react-app" officially rather than using such any library?